Determining statical determinacy of a complex truss
Why is the following structure a mechanism? The explanation given in my school notes is that because all 3 bars connecting the two equilateral triangles are concurrent. I understand that when the support reactions are concurrent, then the system is a mechanism. However, in this case the support reactions are not concurrent but rather it is the bars within the structure that is concurrent. Also, I always thought that a equilateral triangle is the most stable form of a structure.
I think more generally, I want to ask how do we determine if a structure is a mechanism (without using matrix methods as I have yet to get to that).
Thank you!


The middle triangle is free to rotate (small angle approximation) without imposing any forces in the linking bars.
There are various methods of determining whether a pin jointed structure is a mechanism, statically determinant or indeterminate, here's one
https://www.sjsu.edu/people/steven.vukazich/docs/160.3.8%20General%20Determinacy.pdf
I'm a little leary of these small angle approximations and the like since I deal with large angles and so on.
In the small angle approximation the path B of a rod AB with a pinned joint at A is constrained to be perpendicular to the line AB

Hi, may you explain further how small angle approximation shows that the triangle is free to rotate?
